# How to split an array into multiple strings dynamically

Tags: dataweave

input: {
  "id": [
    1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
  ]
}

output: {
"id": [
"1,2,3",
"4,5,6",
"7,8,9",
"10"
]
}

```
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
"id": vars.pd.*id joinBy ","
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `divideBy` function in the `dw::core::Arrays` module.

```
%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays
output application/json
---
"id": payload.id divideBy 3 map ((v) -> v joinBy ",")
```